# Failed to load c++ bson extension while trying to load in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

for the below code, i am getting an error:**Failed to load c++ bson extension**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://jer:jer@ds061621.mongolab.com:61621/trial100');
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.
me working on **windows7**.
Have installed mongoose also.

Answer (score 0):

i did an npm update and it worked fine for me(WINDOWS 7).